# lists of simple types in OData metadata

Tags: types, odata

How can an object with a property of a list of simple (EDM) type be presented in the odata metadata?
for example an object with a list of strings with cardinality of 2..10?

When i try to create a navigation property, assosiation and assotiation set it requires an entity set for the simple type and thats not right...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

OData V3 supports collections of primitive or complex types. In .NET this is implemented in the latest V3 CTP here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/10/13/announcing-wcf-data-services-oct-2011-ctp-for-net-4-and-silverlight-4.aspx

Comment: to my understanding this is only supported in function import and it does not solve the cardinality problem right?

Comment: In V3 collections are supported as properties on complex or entity types just fine. The only thing which is not supported is to have a root-level collection (as that can't exist in EDM either, everything has to start with either an entity set or function).